# Como enviar um arquivo .py para um ambiente virtual específico e transforma-lo em um executável?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, .exe

Boa tarde pessoal, então eu terminei de criar um código em **Python** no **VSCode** e queria saber como transferi-lo para um **Ambiente Virtual** específico e transforma-lo em um executável para enviar para as pessoas até para aqueles que não tem Python instalado no computador.

Como eu faria isso?

Desde já agradeço! :D

Comment: Dé uma olhada no [pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/)

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.